# Understanding the Law(s) of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Theorem $1$: Weak law of Large Numbers**

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be  sequence of i.i.d.s each having mean $E[X_i]=\mu$. Then, for any $\epsilon >0,$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P\left(\left\lvert \frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}- \mu\right\rvert > \epsilon \right ) = 0.$$

**Question $1$**: From what I understand, the WLLN asserts that for $n$ large, $\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$ is likely to be near $\mu$. Am I thus right in claiming that no matter how large $n$ is, there is no guarantee that $\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$ is always going to stay near $\mu?$ More formally, can I say that there is always a non-zero probability (albeit a very small one) such that we have $\left\lvert \frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}- \mu \right\rvert > \epsilon $ no matter what values of $n$ and $\epsilon$ we pick?

**Theorem $2$: Strong law of Large Numbers**

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be  sequence of i.i.d.s each having mean $E[X_i]=\mu$. Then, with probability $1$, we have that:

$$P\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n} = \mu\right)=1.$$

**Question $2$:** I understand that, for the Strong law of Large Numbers, we are considering almost-sure convergence. Hence, unlike the weak law, the strong law asserts that the event $\left\lvert \frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}- \mu \right\rvert > \epsilon $ almost surely does not happen. Indeed, for all sufficiently large values of $n$, the inequality $\left\lvert \frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}- \mu \right\rvert < \epsilon$ always holds (I believe this follows from the epsilon-delta definition). Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: For question 1: You can not rephrase convergence in such way. The limit means that the probability get arbitrarily small. It does not means, that the probability remains positive (no matter how small). It could be zero from the start.

Comment: @user251257 Am I right to say that the "event" $\left\lvert \frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}- \mu \right\rvert > \epsilon$ can happen infinitely often?

Comment: Indeed if you fix $\epsilon>0$ and define $A_n = \left\{|\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n} - \mu|>\epsilon\right\}$ then the weak law implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[A_n]=0$ (but the weak claim $P[A_n]\rightarrow 0$ still leaves open the question of whether or not $A_n$ can occur for infinitely many indices $n$).  The strong law resolves that question: It says  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[\cup_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m]= 0$ and, with prob 1, $A_n$ occurs for an at most finite number of indices $n$.

Comment: Yep, this was clear! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Question 1: Yes, the probability of the event $\{ |\frac{X_1+\cdots + X_n}{n} - \mu | > \epsilon \}$ might be nonzero for any fixed $n$. Think of the following example: $X_1,...,X_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$. Then the probability of interest can be calculated exactly, since $\frac{X_1+\cdots + X_n}{n} \sim N(0, 1/n)$, and  $P\{ |\frac{X_1+\cdots + X_n}{n} | > \epsilon \}=  2\Phi(-\epsilon \sqrt n)$, which converges to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, but is strictly positive for all $n$. Depending on what you assume about the random variables, you might be able to get a better description of how fast this convergence takes place. For example, if the $X_i's$ have a finite variance, then $P\{ |\frac{X_1+\cdots + X_n}{n} -\mu | > \epsilon \} \le Var(X_i)/(n\epsilon)$, which gives you an idea of how fast this probability decreases. This is called Chebyshev's inequality, and it can be improved, AKA the speed this upper bound approaches zero as a function of $n$ increased, if the $X_i's$ have higher order moments, are Gaussian (or subgaussian), etc..

Regarding Question 2: The same example implies   $P\{ |\frac{X_1+\cdots + X_n}{n} - \mu | < \epsilon \}$ may not ever be equal to 1 for any $n$. That is not really what the strong law is guaranteeing. To really understand the strong law, you have to remember that random variables are just (measurable) functions mapping a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ to the real numbers. For every point of the sample space $\omega \in \Omega$,  $|\frac{X_1(\omega)+\cdots + X_n(\omega)}{n} - \mu |$ defines a sequence of real numbers indexed by $n$. The strong law states that if you look at the subset $A \subset \Omega$ where $\omega \in A \iff |\frac{X_1(\omega)+\cdots + X_n(\omega)}{n} - \mu | \to 0, \;\; as \;\; n\to \infty$, then $P(A)=1$. In other words, the set of exceptional points in $\Omega$ where the functions $\frac{X_1(\omega)+\cdots + X_n(\omega)}{n}$ does not converge to $\mu$ must have probability zero. It is a worthwhile exercise to think about, and prove rigorously, why this is a stronger statement than the weak law, although normally this would not be taught until you are taking a course on measure based probability. See this post if your are interested [Strong law of large numbers implies weak law](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2538299/791229)

Comment: Thank you for the nice examples and response!